# Unable to receive json at client

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

My server is as follows:

```
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8092; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){

    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    var responseBody = {
    'foo': 'bar'
    };

    response.write(JSON.stringify(responseBody));
    response.end();    
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

And at the client I listen using:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8092');

socket.on('foo', function(msg){
   console.log(msg);
 });
```

However nothing is outputted to the console. I can see the following being sent continuously on the network:

```
localhost   resource-type-xhr   POST    HTTP    200     
localhost   resource-type-xhr   GET     HTTP    200
```

and http://localhost:8092/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LRMGBeD is returning: `{"foo":"bar"}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please `emit` an event foo @server so that you can listen that using `on` event @client

you need to use socket.io at both the ends (server and client).

server:

```
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    io.socket.emit('foo',{"foo":"bar"});
```

client:

```
socket.on('foo', function(msg){
   console.log(msg);
 });
```